# Google Maps - Custom Tile - URL based

Tags: google-maps

I have a a REST URL that returns a PNG.  Now I need to get that PNG rendered in GMaps.  If I use the getTileURL, new GTileLayerOverlay, and addOverlay, it seems to add the PNG to every GMaps tile.  Anyone have any examples on how to properly render a PNG like this and handle the differnt zooms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make a custom overlay.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to access the tiles directly. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_tiles

Comment: No, I want o add a PNG Overlay. For an example, I am requesting a weather layer representing wind gusts (polygons). I send a REST URL to a vendor, with the request (including a bounding box, ie continential US), they return a single PNG. Now I need to overlay that over Google Maps. The problem is, when I do it now, it overlays the image in every Gmap tile, so the image is repeated across the US. I think I may need to break the PNG up into pieces and drop thme in the approp tiles?

Comment: If you use GTileLayerOverlay it means you want to add a Layer of tiles. If you only want to overlay one image then you need GGroundOverlay instead. But in any case, those are objects from the V2 API which is now deprecated. It would be advisable to look into building your application with the current V3 API which has similar objects.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay